# AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\TAO\Desktop\New\b.py", line 14, in imgs
img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\TAO\\Desktop\\New\\02.png")
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

this error message come when i run my code
i am trying to code for make a registration System and Identity Card printer
first form done with making data import to database using sqlite3 database and tkinter GUI.this form for get data from database and write on photo data.make the identity Card and print it.but when i trying to open image file with Image.Open() it is not working.

```
from PIL import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *

connection = sqlite3.connect("school.db")

tao = Tk()
tao.title("Mayurapada Central Collage")
tao.configure(bg = '#6699ff')
canvas = Canvas(tao,width = 600,height = 400,bg = '#6699ff')

def imgs():

    img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\TAO\\Desktop\\New\\02.png")
    img.show()
    str01 = "Image"
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",75)
    w,h = font.getsize(str01)
    print(str01)


button01 = Button(tao,text = "Preview",bd = 7,padx = 5,pady = 5,command = 
imgs).place(x = 50,y = 300)

canvas.pack()

tao.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is with `import *` it confuses `PIL.Image` with `tkinter.Image`.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageFont

connection = sqlite3.connect("school.db")

tao = Tk()
tao.title("Mayurapada Central Collage")
tao.configure(bg = '#6699ff')
canvas = Canvas(tao,width = 600,height = 400,bg = '#6699ff')

def imgs():

    img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\TAO\\Desktop\\New\\02.png")
    img.show()
    str01 = "Image"
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",75)
    w,h = font.getsize(str01)
    print(str01)


button01 = Button(tao,text = "Preview",bd = 7,padx = 5,pady = 5,command = 
imgs).place(x = 50,y = 300)

canvas.pack()

tao.mainloop()
```