# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Open' (without using from tkinter import *)

Tags: python, tkinter

[AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790540/attributeerror-type-object-image-has-no-attribute-open/53790570)

I found an answer about my problem but still I cannot run the code and still python insists on showing

> AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Open'.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Frame, Label, PhotoImage, Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import json
```

and the code I want to run is:

```
        window1 = tk.Toplevel()
        window1.config(bg='lightgreen')
        window1.title("Form Calcualtion")
        window1.geometry("640x640")
        new_logo=Image.Open("formpic.png")
        r_new_logo=new_logo.resize((640,640),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        logo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(r_new_logo)
        windowlbl=tk.Label(window1,image=logo2).pack()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post your stacktrace, otherwise its difficult to help. Thanks.

Comment: TYPO: `Image.Open` should be `Image.open` small o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather make a comment because I am not sure about this but I can't make any comments yet. Please try open instead of Open and let me know if it helps...

Comment: Good! It would be helpful if you could accept my answer so next time I can comment ;) Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes focusing for a long time such a case it causes overlooking small details.